# Correct way to say "this is where something goes"

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

I'm writing a FAQ for an app and not quite sure if this is written correctly:

> Hier kommen gekaufte Listeneinträge rein, wenn du die vollständige Liste nicht auf einmal kaufst

(answers the question "Was ist das Zwischenlager?")

The other option I have is

> Hier kommen gekaufte Listeneinträge hin, wenn du die vollständige Liste nicht auf einmal kaufst

or only

> Hier kommen gekaufte Listeneinträge, wenn du die vollständige Liste nicht auf einmal kaufst

Maybe also

> Hier werden Listeneinträge verschoben, wenn du sie alle nicht auf einmal kaufst

Or is there a better way to formulate this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"rein" und "hin" als Ortsbeschreibung wird nur umgangssprachlich benutzt!

> rein = hin = hinein

Try something like

> Im Zwischenlager werden einzelne Listeneinträge abgelegt, wenn die Liste nicht vollständig gekauft wird.

or

> Das Zwischenlager dient zur Ablage von einzelnen Listeneinträgen, falls nur ein Teil der Liste gekauft wird.

Comment: Ahh, "ablegen"! The second one sounds good, will use it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid the whole phrasing is somewhat flawed, since (as npe comments) you can buy neither a list nor a list entry (exceptions exist in rare cases, like a list of tax fugitives)

So my proposal would be:

> Wenn alle Artikel von der Liste gekauft werden [... passende Aktion einfügen] ...
>
> Andernfalls werden nur die gekauften Artikel an die xxx-Liste angehängt, die
> übrigen [... z. B. bleiben im Einkaufswagen? ...]

Comment: It's complicated because in my case the link between the list items and the actual products is a bit weak. You're right that it sounds strange, the formulation in the selected answer I think balances this well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this:

> Hier werden gekaufte Listeneinträge abgelegt, wenn du die vollständige Liste nicht auf einmal kaufst

but please note:

- this sounds like a contradiction (*gekaufte* vs. *nicht kaufst*)

> Hier landen **gekaufte** Listeneinträge rein, wenn du die vollständige Liste **nicht** auf einmal **kaufst**

- 'Listeneinträge' sounds a little bit too abstract/technical in my ears,
  you may use 'Artikel' instead

Answer (score 0):

Nothing makes realy sense ...
are the items are marked for later buy 
"Hier kommen Artikel rein für ein späteren Kauf"
or for later delivery

"Hier kommen gekaufte Waren rein, die später zur Lieferung abgerufen werden"